# Javascript - Dynamically change the contents of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that (on page load) changes my margin using the "css" jQuery method...

```
function page_change() {
  var h = window.location.hash;

  switch (h) {
    case 'home':
      $('.page-slide-box').css({marginLeft: 0});
      break;
    case 'history':
      $('.page-slide-box').css({marginLeft: '-820px'});
      break;
    // more cases here.....
  }
}
```

...but after the page is loaded, I'd like to **animate** the change instead. I was thinking I could alter the existing function using replace() (rather than writing another redundant function), like so:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
  var get = page_change.toString();
  var change = get.replace(/css/g, ￼'animate');
  page_change();
}
```

This successfully changes all instances of "css" to "animate" in my page_change() function. How do I get this function to change dynamically once I've replaced the strings? Or is this just a bad idea?

Comment: if you are using php, I would suggest to use a css with php variables like so myFile.css?var=value or replace the function with the new content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, I'd say this is a terrible idea. Why not simply define 1 function that can do both, and use it accordingly:

```
var page_change = function(e)
{
    var method = e instanceof Event ? 'animate' : 'css';
    switch (location.hash)
    {
        case 'home':
            $('.page-slide-box')[method]({marginLeft: 0});
        break;
        //and so on...
    }
};
```

call this function directly, and it'll set the css, use it like so:

```
window.onhaschange = page_change;
```

and it'll `animate` instead of use the `css` method. Easy

If you want to test this easily, you could try this:

```
var page_change = function(e)
{
    var method = e instanceof Event ? 'animate' : 'css';
    console.log(method);
};
document.body.onclick = page_change;
page_change();//logs css
//click the body and... 
//animate will be logged
```

That's, basically, how this works. 
The added benefit of defining a function like this (anonymous function, assigned to a variable or *referenced* by a var) is that you can easily assign a new function to that same variable:

```
var myFunc = function(){ console.log('foo');};
myFunc();//logs foo
myFunc = function(){console.log('bar')};
myFunc();//logs bar
```

This might work for you, too... of course. You can even store the old function:

```
var myFunc = function(){ console.log('foo');};
myFunc();//logs foo
var oldMyFunc = myFunc;
myFunc = function(){console.log('bar')};
myFunc();//logs bar
oldMyFunc();//logs foo
```

Play around with this for a while, to find the approach that fits your needs best (it could well be a combination of the things I talked about in this answer)

Comment: Thanks. This looks good but I'm not that familiar with the proper use of "instanceof" here - I think thats why it's not working for me; I'm just getting the "else" condition of css, no animation.

Comment: If you assign the `page_change` function as event handler (as I did in the last line of code), the `page_change`'s `e` argument will be assigned an event object. That's what the ternary is checking for: if `e` is an instance of the `Event` object, then the `animate` method will be used. if not, `e` will be undefined, or whatever you pass to the function as first argument...

Comment: @Adam: I've also updated my answer, added a couple of additional tips/tricks that might help you

Answer (score 0):

You still need to create a `new Function()` with the body being the body with the replaced `css`, so just write another function in which you can put delays and callbacks and everything else that you need with `animate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a boolean to reflect the page load state (say `loadstatus`), and use it to determine the action. You can use [bracket notation](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-6/querying-and-setting-properties) to trigger the right action:

```
function page_change() {
  var h = window.location.hash,
      action = loadstatus ? 'animate' : 'css';
  //           ^ set loadstatus to true after page load.
  switch (h) {
    case 'home':
      $('.page-slide-box')[action]({marginLeft: 0});
  //                       ^ action used here
      break;
    case 'history':
      $('.page-slide-box')[action]({marginLeft: '-820px'});
      break;
    // more cases here.....
  }
}
```