# Cannot enum properties when using Object.create

Tags: javascript, object, serialization, ecmascript-5

I have an object like

```
var Profile = Object.create(null);
Object.defineProperties(Profile, {
    id: {
        value: "",
        enumerable: true
    },
    name: {
        value: "",
        enumerable: true
    },
    active: {
        value: true,
        enumerable: true
    }
});
```

Now I want to create an Profile instance and give it id and name, and keep active default true, so I do this:

```
var p1 = Object.create(Profile, {
    id: {
        value: "123",
        enumerable: true
    },
    name: {
        value: "hello world",
        enumerable: true
    }
});
```

Then I got an object named p1, but I cannot find "active" in

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p1);
```

Also I cannot use JSON.stringify(p1) to serialize property "active", but I need property "active" can be serializable.

Is this the wrong way I used Object.create? I just want to create a serializable "class" and get it's serializable "instance". How can I do this?

Comment: your properties are non-configurable and non-writeable...

Comment: Why not just `{ id: "123", name: "hello world" }` ? JavaScript is naturally dirty anyway...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem But `p1.id` still become 123 and `p1.name` become "hello world", I don't know why....

Comment: @Virus721 Because I want to have a template like "class" to make objects, and it has some default value, I just need change some value which different to the default value then get a "complete" object. Like here, active needn't be changed so I just write id and name, I hope `JSON.stringify()` can serialize the property "active" but it doesn't.

Comment: @Sunny: Simply because the property `active` does not exist in your `p1` object. [You have to understand how JS resolves properties to their respective values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15174505/1230836). You call `JSON.stringify` on `p1`, the object is unaware of any `active` propery. It's not until you try and access `p1.active` JS will check the _"parent"_ object prior to the `Object.prototype`, and attempt to resolve the expression `p1.active` to a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your usage of `Object.create`, you're not really cloning/copying anything into the resulting object (you call `p1`). First, you have to understand how JS resolves object properties, upon accessing them:

```
J [     p1.active     ]<=========================================================\ \
S p1[active] ==> JS checks instance for property divide                           | |
O  /\ ||                                                                          | |
N  || || --> property found @instance? return value-------------------------------| |
=  || ||                                                                          | |
   || ===========> p1.prototype is found: Profile, check that object              | |
N  ||      ||                                                                     | |
O  ||      ||--> Profile.active found @Profile instance, return-------------------| |
T  ||      ||                                                                     | |
   ||      ==========> Profile.prototype.active (== Object.prototype.active)      | |
J  ||          ||                                                                 | |
S  ||          ||--> property found @Object.prototype, return---------------------|_|
O  ||          ||                                                                 |=|
N  ||          =======>prototype is null, return "undefined.active"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|X|
   ||                                                                             \ /
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~< TypeError can't read property 'x' of undefined
```

That's basically, what can happen. Now upon calling `JSON.stringify(p1)`, JS will just turn to the `p1` object, and process its properties (the ones defined @instance level). The `p1` object *is unaware of there being an `active` property defined on `Profile`*.
`JSON.stringify` only checks the steps I've marked with JSON (the first cycle), all other checks (prototype-chain) is of no interest to JSON. 9/10, this is just the `Object.prototype` anyway, and you don't want to stringify that, now would you?

To be brutally honest, for what you (seemingly) want to accomplish, the easiest solution would be this:

```
p1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Profile));
p1.id = 123;
p1.name = 'hello world';
console.log(JSON.stringify(p1));//will show active property!
```

Check the link in my last comment, for more details on this matter

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and I understand what happened in Object.create() and how js find "active". And I think what I need is "instance" but not "subclass", but Object.create() can only create "subclass" and if I want to get an "instance" I should use new Profile() like I comment in Tibos answer?

Comment: @Sunny: Yes, either create a new instance, or use my last snippet as an example: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Profile))`, this effectively copies the object (not the methods, nor its prototype chain, but you will end up with a new object, that has all properties that were defined @instance level, including the `active` property)

Comment: Mighty perty graph ye have der. Thanks, this actually was something I recently had trouble with and your explanation cleared that right up :)

Answer (score 1):

From the MDN page on getOwnPropertyNames:

> Returns an array of all properties (enumerable or not) found directly
>   upon a given object.

The active property is on the proto object of p1, not on p1.

You can iterate over all properties of p1 (including those on the prototype chain) using the `for in` construct. To create a flat object, you can do this:

```
for (var key in obj) {
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    obj[key] = obj[key];
  }
}
```

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

`for in`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

`Object.create`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: Seems a good way, thanks. By the way, I find a way which use new function to create an object, like: `var Profile = function(syntax){this.id="";this.name="";this.active=false;for(var i in syntax){this[i]=syntax[i];}}` `new Profile({id:123, name: "abc"})`, is Object.create() better than new Function ?