# "varName" in window and varName in window both return true

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, why do *both* of the following return true?

```
> var a; 
undefined
> "a" in window;
true
> a in window;
true
```

Is there some kind of type coercion going on, or does JavaScript store `a` as both a string and as a variable in the window?

Please feel free to rewrite the title of this question - I wasn't sure exactly how to describe this confusing phenomenon.

Comment: I did - the first returns false, the second is a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: that's because b is undefined, and the way your console evaluates the expression (an elaborate `eval` system), it can't scope-scan and create a new implied global... but that's besides the point here. Not that I take offense, but I'd like to know why you accepted the answer that was posted _after_ mine, contained less information and just references my answer for completeness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

```
"a" in window
```

javascript looks for a property called `a` in the window object, and hence returns `true`.

For

```
a in window
```

a evaluates to `undefined` as noted by @Ootegem and hence returns true.

Comment: Oh of course - `a in window` *evaluates* `a`. Duh! Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: When `undefined` is used as a property name it is implicitly converted to a string - which happens to be `'undefined'`. Thus `undefined in window` is equivalent to `'undefined' in window`.

Answer (score 6):

No, you declared a variable called `a`, which is initialized to `undefined`. This variable is global, so it can be accessed as a sort-of property of the global object (window), so:

```
var a = {};//an obejct
var b = {};//another
b === a //false, two separate objects, of course but
window.a === a;//true
```

That's why `'a' in window` is true. It's similar to `window.hasOwnProperty('a');`. Similar, not the same thing.

The second check you did (`a in window`) is evaluated to `undefined in window`, in turn the value `undefined` is stringified, so the expression is finally evaluated to `'undefined in window'`, which is always going to be true.
I admit, this is confusing, because `undefined` is both a value and a property, which doesn't really make sense. It's just one of the quirks in JS you have to learn to live with. You can verify this like so:

```
window.hasOwnProperty('undefined');//true
window.undefined;//undefined of course
window.hasOwnProperty('null');//false
typeof null;//object (really! But it is actually a primitive 
typeof undefined;//undefined
```

`null` is an object for historic reasons, but I'm not going to give you *"The unabridged history of ECMAScript"*, Just thought you might like to know that.

What you have to keep in mind is how JS resolves variable names, and expressions. [I've explained this many times, see this answer and all of the links at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174505/1230836) for details on the matter

Comment: Nit 1: `undefined in window` works because it is equivalent to `'undefined' in window` - it is the stringification of the property name that makes it work. That is, `undefined` (the value) is *not* a property, but `'undefined'` is.

Comment: Nit 2: `null` is a [*primitive* value](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.2) and *not* an object. `typeof` is misleading here - just as it returns `"function"` for Function objects, but `"object"` for Array objects .. It is just how `typeof` works.

Comment: @user2864740: On both nits: I don't contradict/say otherwise. Or at least, I never meant to. I'll edit the stringification of `undefined` bit to be more clear, but I added `window.undefined` which sort of implies that undefined is stringified in the `a in window` case... On null being an `object`: I clearly stated that this is down to historic reasons, not because `null` is an object

Comment: I've not said this answer was wrong (and indeed it got my positive vote), just throwing in some finer details - for those who are actually concerned with such :|

Comment: @user2864740: Didn't mean to come across all defensive, just wanted to clarify I didn't mean to say anything else. Took your comments to heart and edited my answer to avoid any confusion.