# How javascript this keyword works in below code

Tags: javascript

We can't change the below code:

```
var t = 10;

function test(){
  var t = 20;
  alert(this.t);
}
```

We have to change or add below this.

`test();`

the above function call execute 10;

I need "20" which is defined inside the function test.

Comment: Then, use `this.t = 20;`..

Comment: Is that a puzzle or a real practical question ?

Comment: @dystroy Sorry It is a challenge given to me.

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: Thanks jcubic and all other answers and discussions. Really brief enough about this keyword in this scenario.

Comment: what would happen if i use like this,

var tt = new test();
tt.t = 20;

Answer (score 3):

Since you cannot change the function, you can do this

```
test = test.bind({t: 20});
test();
```

Or in a single line

```
test.bind({t: 20})();
```

Comment: You didn't read the first line of the question, did you ?

Comment: @dystroy you are correct. We cant change inside function. Is there any object initiation or some thing else for test function?

Comment: @dystroy Well, I had to think for a while after seeing your first comment. But I believe our answers have different impacts. My first version binds the object. So, next time onwards he doesn't have to pass the object :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :

```
test.call({t:20});
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to read up on how JS resolves names (through scope scanning, namely), and how the `this` keyword is bound. [I've dealt with this in detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174505/1230836), and linked to other resources which goes into more detail of several aspects.

The long and short of it is that your function should look like this:

```
function f ()
{
    var t = 20;
    alert(t);//console.log would be better, though
}
```

With the code, as it stands, you can't get to the `var` value. You'll have to change some of the code, or change how you invoke the function:

```
var obj = {t: 20, test: test};//test is the function name:
obj.test();//this.t will reference obj.t now
```

Read the linked answers why and how this works

Answer (score 0):

if you call `test()` it will be as a function and `this` will be global object (window). if you add `new` keyword (`new test();`) then it will be an object and `this` will refer to that object. But you will need to also store t in this:

```
function test(){
  this.t = 20;
  alert(this.t);
}

new test();
```

or you can store that in var and access it using that var:

```
function test(){
  var t = 20;
  alert(t);
}

test();
```

Comment: My original answer had something similar, but the question's first line reads `We can't change the below code:` :)

Comment: @user3350129 it's valid question. The answer is that you can't get `var t = 20;` using `this.t;` it's different variable. it's like access `var x` with `y`.

Comment: Thanks jcubic and all other answers and discussions. Really brief enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :

```
alert(20);
```

Seriously, you've probably misunderstood your teacher's instructions.