# Class/instance method overrides in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, overriding, static-methods

Is it generally acceptable and reasonable to define class (static) and prototype methods with the same name in JS? In the following `node.js` example the method `update` is defined in such a way and the example works like a charm, but are there any common cases when this could cause issues, for example, such as calling `update` on an instance would dispatch to the class method?

```js
function Base(id, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;
    Base.objects[id] = this;
}

Base.objects = {};

Base.find = function(id, done) {
    var err = null;
    var obj = this.objects[id];
    if (!obj) {
        err = new Error("no obj found for id " + id);
    }
    done(err, obj);
};

Base.update = function(id, value, done) {
    this.find(id, function(err, obj) {
        if (err) {
            done(err);
        } else {
            obj.update(value, done);
        }
    });
};

Base.prototype.update = function(value, done) {
    this.value = value;
    done();
};
```

Trying it out:

```js
new Base('aa', 1);
new Base('bb', 2);

Base.update('aa', 3, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
});

Base.update('bb', 5, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
});

console.log(Base.objects);
```

Output:

```
{ aa: { id: 'aa', value: 3 }, bb: { id: 'bb', value: 5 } }
```

Comment: JavaScript constructor functions and prototype are a bit strange maybe, I have tried to explain it's behavior in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're asking here, but I take it you're wondering if you were to call:

```
(new Base('aa', 1)).update(3, function (err){ if (err) throw err;});
```

That this *could* invoke the `Base.update` function.

The answer to that question is, of course: ***No***.

The `Base.update` function has nothing to do with `Base.prototype.update`. A function, like almost everything in JS, is an object. Just like the `Base` instances you create with `new Base`. The `Base` function (that just happens to double as a constructor) has its own inheritance chain:

```
Base //the object itself
  || Object.getPrototypeOf(Base)
  ====> Function (or function Empty(){} in chromium)
         || Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Base));
         ====> Object {}
```

When you create a new `Base` object, that chain looks like this:

```
x // Base instance itself
 ||
  --> Base.prototype //or Base {} <-- an object!
       ||
        --> Object{}
```

That means that any property of any `Base` instance has to be located along that inheritance chain: either defined on the object itself, on the `Base.prototype` object, or on the mother of all object: `Object`.

At no point will the ***function object*** `Base` be considered.

So, what does this all mean, exactly:

```
var x = new Base('x', 1);
console.log(x.update === Base.prototype.update);//true
console.log(x.update === Base.update);//false, of course
```

But if you were to write:

```
x.update = Base.update;
```

Then you've overridden the prototype, and calling `update` on `x` (this one instance of `Base`), then `Base.update` will be invoked.
However, it'll not work as expected, because its call context has changed. `this` references `x` now and this statement:

```
 this.find(...)
```

will no longer work, unless you also add `x.find = Base.find`. However, now we have a similar problem in the `x.find` method:

```
var obj = this.objects[id];
```

`x` does not have an `objects` property... to fix that, you'll have to add `x.objects = Base.objects` to make it all work. We end up with:

```
x = new Base('x', 1);
x.update = Base.update;
x.find = Base.find;
x.objects = Base.objects;
```

But now we've assigned all properties of the `Base` function object to `x`, a `Base` instance. That's just silly, so let's delete them:

```
delete(x.update);
delete(x.find);
delete(x.objects);
```

Now, `x.update` will, once again work as expected: the instance itself doesn't mask the prototype methods, so that's what will be invoked.

This is just a quick canter through how JS evaluates expressions and how prototypes (and scopes) are scanned. [I've explained it all before here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174505/1230836), at length. This linked answer also contains more links, each to answers that are in some way related to the same thing (scopes and prototype chains).

Comment: I was asking exactly this. So thanks for your comprehensive answer. Depending on language the behaviour is not immediately obvious. Java does not allow such overrides at all (for identical arguments), python allows them (although expects different arguments) and will dispatch to the class method if the instance method is not available (e.g. dynamically removed). Therefore, it is good not only to see it working, but also to understand why.

Comment: @OlegS.: I couldn't agree more... It's fine to see that something works, but it's even better to _know_ the why and how! That said: If your background is Java and Python, then I'd urge you to spend some time getting to grips with the quirks of a prototype based system. They're quite different. The only reason why this isn't immediately obvious is because JS is a language that takes quite a lot of abuse, and can be forced into a more classical OO style, but it doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

JS is prototype-based language. In this language calling on method from some object is exactly calling that function that is stored in object itself with that name or in it's `__proto__` of some level.

The mismatch you've interested in is only possible when `SomeObj.prototype==SomeObj`. If you wouldn't do such a thing this won't appear at any time.